# Hive can't create partitioned column for external table in hbase

Tags: sql, hadoop, hbase, hive

I cant create external table with partitioned column in hive with the below script

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Opportunity_par(key string,Opportunity__Id string,Campaign__Name string)
    > PARTITIONED BY (eventDate timestamp)
    > STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
    > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf2:Opportunity__Id,cf3:Campaign__Name,cf1:eventDate")
    > TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "test_table");
```

its showing the following error,

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe: columns has 3 elements while hbase.columns.mapping has 4 elements (counting the key if implicit))
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Please give solution or suggestion for creating external table in hive with partitioning column

Thanks all...

Comment: Partitioning a table that is backed by HBase doesn't really make sense in the first place. What are you expecting to happen? Partitions in Hive are really just HDFS directories, but you're not using HDFS.

Comment: I want to create a hive table for quering with partitioned column for my hbase (test_table) table, if i tried to do that i ended with above error...what should do @JoeK

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the HBase angle, but...

A partition is just a sub folder inside the table folder. Note that all Hive tables(metadata and data) exist only on HDFS (or other supported systems) and not local file system.

Partitions on an external table is tricky because: An external table just points to data existing in a Pre-existing location/folder. If the folder is pre-existing that means most likely there is no subfolder inside it which corresponds to the partition. So, in order to create/add a partition to an external table, it either has to have a pre-existing subfolder for the partition, or you have to manually create one.

Look at this for some more information: http://blog.zhengdong.me/2012/02/22/hive-external-table-with-partitions